# Can I use Flyway with the SQL Server encryption?

Tags: sql-server, flyway, windows-server-2012-r2, sql-server-2017

In our test environments we use flyway. Now we want to use it on our productive systems too.

On this systems we force the SQL Server encryption so flyway can't communicate with our database.

I get following error:

> D:\flyway-6.2.0>flyway info
>   Database password:
>   Flyway Community Edition 6.2.0 by Redgate
>   ERROR:
>   Unable to obtain connection from database (jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:*Port*;
>   databaseName=*myDatabase*;integratedSecurity=true;) for user '********': 
>   I/O Error: DB server closed connection.
>   SQL State  : 08S01
>   Error Code : 0
>   Message    : I/O Error: DB server closed connection.

Does anybody know this problem and can help me?

Answer (score 4):

Flyway started supporting the 'integratedSecurity=true' jdbc parameter in Flyway 6.2.4 ([release notes](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/releaseNotes#6.2.4)), so if you upgrade to that version or later it should work. It also requires the sqljdbc_auth.dll to be available on the classpath.

Required steps taken from https://flywaydb.org/documentation/database/sqlserver#authentication.

Windows Authentication and Azure Active Directory require an extra driver to be installed:

1. Go to the ‘Download Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server’ page
2. Download the .tar.gz file for the JDBC version used by Flyway
3. The version can be seen in the ‘Maven Central coordinates’ url under the Driver section at the top of this page
4. Extract the contents of the file
5. Look for sqljdbc_auth.dll, under sqljdbc_{version}\enu\auth\x64
   Copy sqljdbc_auth.dll to an accessible location in your environment (e.g. C:\jdbc-drivers)
6. Add the location of sqljdbc_auth.dll to your PATH environment variable